# How do I compare an IO String with a String, print a message if false, and return the value?

Tags: haskell, types, io

I don't know if this has been asked before, but I haven't got anywhere from Googling.
I want to have the following code's equivalent in Haskell:

```py
def inputThing(string: str) -> bool:
  a=input("Input: ")
  if a=="Hello":
    return True
  else:
    print("Not hello")
    return False
```

What I came up with is something like this:

```hs
import System.IO ( hFlush, stdout )
inputThing :: String -> IO Bool
inputThing string = do
  putStr "Input:"
  hFlush stdout
  input <- getLine
  if string == input then True else putStrLn "Not hello" >> False
```

that last line I simplified to (or rather the linter suggested)

```hs
(string == input) || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> False)
```

But I get various errors that all seem to have something to do with things being IO typed or not:

```hs
thing.hs:7:3: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO Bool’ with actual type ‘Bool’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        (string == input) || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> False)
      In the expression:
        do putStr "Input:"
           hFlush stdout
           input <- getLine
           (string == input) || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> False)
      In an equation for ‘inputThing’:
          inputThing string
            = do putStr "Input:"
                 hFlush stdout
                 input <- getLine
                 ....
  |
7 |   (string == input) || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> False)
  |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

thing.hs:7:25: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘IO b0’
    • In the second argument of ‘(||)’, namely
        ‘(putStrLn "Not hello" >> False)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        (string == input) || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> False)
      In the expression:
        do putStr "Input:"
           hFlush stdout
           input <- getLine
           (string == input) || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> False)
  |
7 |   (string == input) || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> False)
  |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

thing.hs:7:49: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO b0’ with actual type ‘Bool’
    • In the second argument of ‘(>>)’, namely ‘False’
      In the second argument of ‘(||)’, namely
        ‘(putStrLn "Not hello" >> False)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        (string == input) || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> False)
  |
7 |   (string == input) || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> False)
  |                                                 ^^^^^
```

The best I could think of was:

```hs
(fmap ((==) string) input) || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> return False)
```

This still doesn't work:

```hs
thing.hs:7:3: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO Bool’ with actual type ‘Bool’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        (fmap ((==) string) input)
          || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> return False)
      In the expression:
        do putStr "Input:"
           hFlush stdout
           input <- getLine
           (fmap ((==) string) input)
             || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> return False)
      In an equation for ‘inputThing’:
          inputThing string
            = do putStr "Input:"
                 hFlush stdout
                 input <- getLine
                 ....
  |
7 |   (fmap ((==) string) input) || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> return False)
  |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

thing.hs:7:4: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘[Bool]’
    • In the first argument of ‘(||)’, namely
        ‘(fmap ((==) string) input)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        (fmap ((==) string) input)
          || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> return False)
      In the expression:
        do putStr "Input:"
           hFlush stdout
           input <- getLine
           (fmap ((==) string) input)
             || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> return False)
  |
7 |   (fmap ((==) string) input) || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> return False)
  |    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

thing.hs:7:23: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected: [String]
        Actual: String
    • In the second argument of ‘fmap’, namely ‘input’
      In the first argument of ‘(||)’, namely
        ‘(fmap ((==) string) input)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        (fmap ((==) string) input)
          || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> return False)
  |
7 |   (fmap ((==) string) input) || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> return False)
  |                       ^^^^^

thing.hs:7:34: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘IO Bool’
    • In the second argument of ‘(||)’, namely
        ‘(putStrLn "Not hello" >> return False)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        (fmap ((==) string) input)
          || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> return False)
      In the expression:
        do putStr "Input:"
           hFlush stdout
           input <- getLine
           (fmap ((==) string) input)
             || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> return False)
  |
7 |   (fmap ((==) string) input) || (putStrLn "Not hello" >> return False)
  |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

At this point I thought "Surely there's a much simpler way of doing this I haven't thought of" but as previously mentioned, Googling wasn't getting me far, so I decided to post this.

I am very certain it is the case that you cannot convert an IO String to a String - but I'm guessing there's a way to get a IO Bool that returns the comparison of an IO String to a String - however, as shown, I didn't get anywhere with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`True` and `False` have type `Bool`, but the result needs to be of type `IO Bool`. This way, there's actually an easy and sensible conversion (unlike `IO Bool` to `Bool`, which is not possible): this is what [`return`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:return) does! So it actually looks *more similar* to Python:

```
   if string == input
    then return True
    else putStrLn "Not hello" >> return False
```

or, depending on your taste in code layout

```
   if string == input then
       return True
    else do
       putStrLn "Not hello"
       return False
```

or shorter, applicative-style:

```
   if string == input
    then pure True
    else False <$ putStrLn "Not hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

The linter put you on the wrong path. All you need to do is add a `pure` or two:

```
import System.IO ( hFlush, stdout )
inputThing :: String -> IO Bool
inputThing string = do
  putStr "Input:"
  hFlush stdout
  input <- getLine
  if string == input then pure True else putStrLn "Not hello" >> pure False
```

Comment: What does ```pure``` do though?

Comment: In this case, it changes a `Bool` into an `IO Bool`

Comment: Then what's the difference between ```pure``` and ```return```?

Comment: It's basically a different name for the same thing. Technically `pure` is a method of the `Applicative` typeclass and `return` is a function that requires a `Monad`, so `pure` is a little bit more general. But I also prefer `pure` to avoid the confusion with the `return` keyword from imperative languages (which is subtly different).